# Oracle case statement with variable

Tags: oracle, case, ora-06550, pls-00103

I have a requirement which says run one query if today is monday, else run another query. For this I have wrote the below query, but I am getting the below error message.

```
DECLARE
   l_today_date VARCHAR2(15) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DAY');
 BEGIN
   CASE l_today_date
   WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN
     (SELECT st_time AS SYS_DATE,
       start_time                          AS JOB_START_TIME,
       COALESCE (end_job,'Job Is Running') AS JOB_END_TIME,
       CASE duration_job
         WHEN ' min'
         THEN 'Job is Running'
         ELSE duration_job
       END AS JOB_DURATION,
       CASE duration_job
         WHEN ' min'
         THEN 'Job is Running'
         ELSE 'Complete'
       END AS job_status
     FROM
       (SELECT name,
         st_time,
         ABS(floor(((((st_time - lag(end_time) over (order by end_time desc))*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60))
         || ' min' duration_job,
         TO_CHAR(st_time, 'hh24:mi:ss')      AS start_time,
         TO_CHAR(lag(end_time)over(order by end_time desc),'hh24:mi:ss') AS end_job
       FROM sc_stask
       WHERE name IN ( '111 has started' ,'111 has ended' )
       ORDER BY st_time DESC
       )
     WHERE name = '111 has started');
   ELSE
     (SELECT st_time                       AS SYS_DATE,
       start_time                          AS JOB_START_TIME,
       COALESCE (end_job,'Job Is Running') AS JOB_END_TIME,
       CASE duration_job
         WHEN ' min'
         THEN 'Job is Running'
         ELSE duration_job
       END AS JOB_DURATION,
       CASE duration_job
         WHEN ' min'
         THEN 'Job is Running'
         ELSE 'Complete'
       END AS job_status
     FROM
       (SELECT name,
         st_time,
         ABS(floor(((((st_time - lag(end_time)over(order by end_time desc) )*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60))
         || ' min' duration_job,
         TO_CHAR(st_time, 'hh24:mi:ss')      AS start_time,
         TO_CHAR(lag(end_time)over(order by end_time desc),'hh24:mi:ss') AS end_job
       FROM sc_stask
       WHERE name                      IN ( '111 has started' ,'111 has completed' )
       AND TO_CHAR(st_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')
       ORDER BY st_time DESC
       )
     WHERE name = '111 has started'
     );
   END CASE;
   dbms_output.Put_line(l_today_date);
END;
```

Here is the error message I am having

```
 Error report -
 ORA-06550: line 6, column 6:
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

    ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
    date <a string literal with character set specification>
    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
    <an alternat
 ORA-06550: line 22, column 47:
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "OVER" when expecting one of the following:

    . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
    like4 likec as between || member submultiset
 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
 *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Can someone please help me how to get over this. Also, the queries that run in each of the case statement work absolutely fine individually. But when I put them back into one, they don't.

Comment: Is the procedure meant to return a ref cursor? I don't see any `into` to hold hold variables or an `out` parameter to pass anything back to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the parentheses; you should not have those around the select statements:

```
DECLARE
   l_today_date VARCHAR2(15) := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');
 BEGIN
   CASE l_today_date
   WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN
     SELECT st_time AS SYS_DATE,
...
     WHERE name = '111 has started';
   ELSE
     SELECT st_time                       AS SYS_DATE,
...
     WHERE name = '111 has started';
   END CASE;
   dbms_output.Put_line(l_today_date);
END;
/
```

I've also added the optional third argument to `to_char()` so make sure the day name is one you're searching for; otherwise if someone runs this from a non-English session it won't match properly.

---

Incidentally, if you were only using the `l_tdoay_date` value once - and didn't have the `dbms_output` debugging call at the end - you wouldn't need that variable; you can use `case` with the function call:

```
BEGIN
   CASE TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
   WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN
...
```

And you could use `if` instead of `case` here - either works but with only one value being checked you probably aren't gaining much from using `case` in this example.

---

You could also use a single query and move the case statement logic into its `where` clause, something like:

```
   FROM sc_stask
   WHERE name IN ( '111 has started' ,'111 has ended' )
   AND (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'MONDAY'
     OR TO_CHAR(st_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')
   )
```

though I'd generally do that last part as `OR TRUNC(st_time) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)` rather than converting both to strings. Anyway, with that approach you may not need the PL/SQL block at all; and if you do have it then as @Littlefoot mentioned you have to select (either) query *INTO* something.

Answer (score 1):

Not `CASE`, but `IF`:

```
begin
  if to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') = 'MONDAY' then
     select ... query you run on monday;
  else
     select ... query you run otherwise
  end if;
end;
```

**[EDIT: added example for the INTO clause]**

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3    l_today varchar2(10) := to_char(sysdate, 'DAY');
  4  begin
  5    if l_today = 'THURSDAY' then
  6       select count(*)
  7         into l_cnt          --> this
  8         from emp
  9         where deptno = 10;
 10    else
 11       select count(*)
 12         into l_cnt
 13         from emp
 14         where deptno <> 10;
 15    end if;
 16
 17    dbms_output.put_line('Today is ' || l_today || ' and count = ' || l_cnt);
 18  end;
 19  /
Today is THURSDAY  and count = 11

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Either works; with only one value being checked `IF` seems the more obvious choice, but `CASE` isn't wrong. You have also removed the parentheses though, which were what was actually causing the error *8-)

Comment: Actually, @Alex, both are *wrong* in this case - there's no `INTO` (or I don't see it, or there's something else I didn't notice), so they'll fail anyway.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use into command, as I don't have the right to create a table or a temporary table as well. I just have access to execute queries

Comment: I edited my message and included an example for the INTO clause. Note that - if your query returns more than a single row - you'll have to do *something* differently (for example, loop and use the same INTO, or return a refcursor, or ...).

Comment: @Littlefoot, as you see I am in need of multiple columns, which I have created as variables and am able to insert into them. But when I am trying to retrieve the values of those variables, I am not able to get it. I tried using dbms_output.Put_line(v_status); but this is printing the output in the scriptoutput tab but not query result tab.splunk is considering that there is no output. Also, when I run this in Splunk where I am trying to run the query, I am getting the below error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 5: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting